# How do I convert console output to a string?

Tags: c#

I am making a very simple C# program that outputs text and trying to test it. My test keeps failing because the text from the console does not equal the text I am comparing it to. I think it is just not being converted to a string correctly, but I don't know.
Here is the program code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab3._1
{
    public class ConsoleOutput
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Lab3._1Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ConsoleOutputTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void WriteToConsoleTest()
        {
            var currentConsoleOut = Console.Out;
            string newConsoleOut = currentConsoleOut.ToString();

            string ConsoleOutput = "Hello World!";

            Assert.AreEqual(newConsoleOut, ConsoleOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Test Failed - WriteToConsoleTest
Message: Assert.AreEqual failed.
Expected:<System.IO.TextWriter+SyncTextWriter>.Actual:<Hello World!>.
```

Comment: Set a break point before the Assertion and see what's the `newConsoleOut`, `currentConsoleOut` is.

Comment: Have you set a *breakpoint* to verify what `newConsoleOut` is?

Comment: I'm trying to check if the console output is equal to the string "Hello World!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test never calls `ConsoleOutput.Main` so `Hello World!` is never written to the console.  You're then calling `ToString` on a `TextWriter` and comparing it to a `string`, so you're comparing apples and oranges.

If you want to capture what's written to the console, you should redirect it to an alternate `TextWriter` implementation:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WriteToConsoleTest()
{
    // setup test - redirect Console.Out
    var sw = new StringWriter();    
    Console.SetOut(sw);

    // exercise system under test
    ConsoleOutput.Main();

    // verify
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello World!\r\n", sw.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This works when the last line is changed from "Equal" to "AreEqual"

Comment: @MichaelReuter sorry, force of habit and not paying attention.  I don't use MSTest.

Answer (score 2):

You have got in a bit of a muddle over how to set console redirection, write to it and then read the results. To achieve what you are trying to do, change your test method to:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WriteToConsoleTest()
{
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        Console.SetOut(sw);
        ConsoleOutput.Main();

        Assert.AreEqual("Hello World!" + Environment.NewLine, sw.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems right but I'm still getting an error: Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected<Hello World!>. Actual:<Hello World!>. They look the same to me!

Comment: Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected<Hello World!>. Actual:<Hello World!>.

Comment: @MichaelReuter, Did you catch my edit of adding `Environment.NewLine` to "Hello World!"?

Comment: Just added it! Looks a little nicer than the return.